# How could one geometrically visualize any given metric space $(X,d)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, visualization

> **Example.** Say $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,y)=\frac{d_0(x,y)}{1+d_0(x,y)}$ where $d_0(x,y)=|x-y|$ is the Euclidean metric.

The visualization of e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ with Eucledian distance $d_0(x,y)=|x-y|$ is clear, because it coincides with the intuitive distance between two points on a real line.

However if one changes the metric to be $d(x,y)=\frac{d_0(x,y)}{1+d_0(x,y)}$ it seems not obvious to me what a visualization could look like. Changing the metric of course changes the open and closed sets; how do these changed open and closed sets look on the real line?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: That depends heavily on the set and metric in question. There are multiple metrics on $\mathbb{R}$, the space itself can always be visualized as the real line but the distance between points need not be given by what you would intuitively describe as the distance between those points. You can imagine certain parts being more difficult to travel through and hence yielding more distance and other parts being easier to traverse. In general there is no way to visualize these things.

Comment: From an analytical point of viewe, and asuming you are content that the above expression does indeed give a metric space, then consider the monotinicity of $f(t)=t/(1+t)$ and you may be able to 'visualise' the metric funciton a little, but in general I agree with Mathematician42 above.

Answer (score 1):

Say $(X,d)$ is a *metric space*. The open discs in $X$ form a base for the topology induced by $d$.

An *open disc* $D_\epsilon (x)$ with radius $\epsilon>0$ and midpoint $x\in X$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is defined as $$D_\epsilon (x):=\{y\in X| d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$$

For $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ these are some examples of open discs 
$$D_{1/2}(0)=(-1,1)$$
$$D_{2/3}(0)=(-2,2)$$
$$D_{3/4}(0)=(-3,3)$$

Generally:

$$D_{n/(n+1)}(x)=(x-n,x+n)$$

Saying this means, that you can still visualize the open sets in $X=\mathbb{R}$ induced by above metric as unions of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ - the changed metric in your case did not alter the open (and the closed) sets / **the metrics induce the same topology**.

Comment: A general approach for *visualizing a metric space* $(X,d)$ can be a weighted (undirected) graph with vertices $V=X$ and edges $E=V\times V$ with weights $d(x,y)$ for any edge $(x,y)$. You can at least visualize any finite subgraph of such a representation.

Comment: It seems we understand the word "visualize" very differently. You know, an uncountable graph with uncountable number of edges starting at each vertex isn't exactly what I would call a "visualization". Actually it would probably be more confusing to me than simple metric formula.

Comment: @freakish Aggreed (and I did not suggest infinite graphs as a sort of visualization but visualizations of finite subgraphs). Actually this can be useful depending on the specific thing or aspect you intend to visualize. E.g. in an engineering context or in natural sciences you will often find yourself working with a metric space that is modeling some measurements or system states. In these contexts you will often not be interested in general properties of that space, but in some relations or developments of finitely many entities in your metric space.

Answer (score 0):

While visualizations may be helpful I suggest actually **not focusing** on them since that road is doomed to fail. And I will try to explain why:

> Changing the metric of course changes the open and closed sets;

Is that so? Well, it might change open balls but all open sets? No, there are many metrics producing the same topology. And there are even different metrics producing same balls, e.g. for real $c>0$ put $d_c(x,y)=c$ and note that all $d_c$ produce the same topology and even exactly the same balls. These are discrete metrics.

> how do these changed open and closed sets look on the real line?

Possibly very insane, impossible to comprehend by a mortal ;)

For example for any $n>0$ there is a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ making $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric. This is a consequence of the fact that both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the same cardinality.

So can you visualize a $12$ dimensional space? And not only that but pack it into the real line? I dare you to do that.

Or lets get it simplier: visualize a discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. So you start with drawing points separated from each other by a distance $1$ on the plane, right? Wait a minute, on a plane? But $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and here's were our intuition collapses: an uncountable subset of a plane **cannot** be discrete. How can you visualize it then? Because there surely is some quantity making it different from a countable discrete subset that can be embedded into a plane.

But lets get it even simplier. Forget about metrics, what is the real line anyway? How can you visualize it? I mean its like a very dense line, right? But so is $\mathbb{Q}$? And yet we know $\mathbb{R}$ is a lot "bigger". So visualize me a difference between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I remember this one being very tricky for me long time ago. I never truely understood it (in terms of intuitive imagination) to be honest. I simply acknowledged it as "it is how it is".

So how come we don't ask questions about visualizing $\mathbb{R}$ to begin with? It doesn't seem easier then exotic metrics. I think that the answer is very simple: the power of habit. We simply got used to the real line, I mean we hear about it since childhood. And the real line itself became a base block for other visualizations.

So here's my answer: get used to exotic metrics and you'll be fine.

Comment: Quote. *So visualize me the difference between* $\mathbb{Q}$
 *and* $\mathbb{R}$. You could e.g. visualize (imagine) the *rational line* as the *real line* with a **dense set of holes** in it (i.e. the irraitonals). (I don't mean that you can precisely draw this but it might offer a mental image).